# short timestamp in symfony 1.4 and doctrine 1.2

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I generated new project in Symfony and I used Doctrine:

```
expires_at:   { type: timestamp, notnull: true }
```

but it is too long for me. I need only 2011/06/05. How can I achieve this? The widget in the form is asking for too much. One must also fill in for example milliseconds.

This:

```
unset(
  $this['expires_at']
);
```

deleted all field in the widget. I would like something like that remained 2011/06/05.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doctrine has a special datatype for this purpose : http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/pl/defining-models:columns:data-types#date

Put this in your schema.yml :

```
expires_at:   { type: date, notnull: true }
```

and regenerate your form.

Comment: @Dsadasda Sdasd : like described here : http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/01-Form-Creation#chapter_01_sub_defining_default_values_for_fields